# trigger jquery click

Tags: jquery, events, click, triggers

I use jquery to build treeview via ajax which has refreshed automatically every 5 second. And I want after building the tree, one of the branches to be selected automatically. But when I use `$('#treeview li span.Running').click();`, nothing happens.

I catch the click event using

```
$('#treeview li span').live('click',function(){
  ....
});
```

I tried with `jQuery` instead of `$` and it was unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance.
BR.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code, or ideally an example online? Cheers :)

Comment: I dont think it is because what you're doing, it should be because when you're doing it, you should do that by traversing to the newly loaded element, in a callback after filetree is fully rendered. Sinan.

Comment: I have 3 functions for that
initSnmpTreeview();
ajaxBuildSnmpTreeview();
showFirstSnmpNode();
You can see that I initialize the main tree then fill it with branches and the last function is to trigger the click event.

Comment: I think I do it on the right place, because I can get and print the text of the <span>, but I still can`t trigger the click event.

Comment: Why edit a question asked 6 years ago..?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the trigger method to trigger an event

```
 $('#treeview li span.Running').click();
```

should be:

```
 $('#treeview li span.Running').trigger('click');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that $('#treeview li span.Running') is selecting the item that you are hoping it will?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I check it several times. I use $(object).click(); trigger many times and it work fine, but I never use it on dynamically load content, so I think the problem is in the dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

My function for catching the event was written after the function for triggering the event. When I move the catching function at the front everything start to work correctly.